# Lower Bound of Entire Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function such that $|f(z)|\ge|z|^\alpha$ for all $|z|\le1$, where $\alpha=\frac{2019}{2020}$. Prove $|f(0)|\ge1$.

I want to apply maximum modulus principle to $\frac{1}{f(z)}$; however, I need to find out a way to ensure $f(0)\neq0$. Can anyone give me any hint about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: If $f(0)=0$ then $f(z)= \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_nz^{n}$ and $\frac  {f(z)} z$ is bounded in $\{z: 0<|z| <1\}$. But the given inequality makes this impossible because $\alpha <1$. ( $\frac {|z|^{\alpha}} {|z|} \to \infty$ as $z \to 0$).  So $f(0) \neq 0$.